# Mapas offline en android studio

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando con osmdroid en un proyecto en android studio 3.5 (api 29), el hecho es que quiero trabajar con mapas offline, he descargado el mapa utilizando MOBAC (como explica la doc de osmdroid) pero cuando ejecuto la app no abre el mapa, carga los marcadores que tengo establecidos y todo, pero no muestra el mapa, a[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]lguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo??? En la imágen se ve como sale...

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //handle permissions first, before map is created. not depicted here

        //load/initialize the osmdroid configuration, this can be done
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        //setting this before the layout is inflated is a good idea
        //it 'should' ensure that the map has a writable location for the map cache, even without permissions
        //if no tiles are displayed, you can try overriding the cache path using Configuration.getInstance().setCachePath
        //see also StorageUtils
        //note, the load method also sets the HTTP User Agent to your application's package name, abusing osm's tile servers will get you banned based on this string

        //inflate and create the map
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        map = findViewById(R.id.mapboxView);
//        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        map.setUseDataConnection(false);
        XYTileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("/storage/emulated/0/osmdroid/Cuba.sqlite", 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[] {""});
        map.setTileSource(tileSource);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(9.5);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(22.172769, -80.448266);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

        /**
         * Habilitar la rotación
         */
        RotationGestureOverlay mRotationGestureOverlay = new RotationGestureOverlay(getApplicationContext(), map);
        mRotationGestureOverlay.setEnabled(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        map.getOverlays().add(mRotationGestureOverlay);
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], agrega información de lo que has realizado para que obtengas la ayuda requerida por parte de la comunidad, ya definiste los permisos necesarios como <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ?

Comment: si, todo esta definido, de hecho conectado a internet funciona, pero cuando intento cargar los mapas locales, no los encuentra.

Comment: Agrega el código que estas realizando

Comment: ese es el código que estoy utilizando, no lanza ningun error, simplemente, no muestra el mapa, que esta en la ruta que le indique en "tileSource", el mapa esta en formato sqlite, lo descargué mediante MOBAC